# Simple way to implement current month in Django template?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am looking for a simple way to implement the current month in my template, in the spelled out format, e.g. "June". So this:
`"The current month is:" {{ code here }}` should produce `The current month is: June"`

I could create my own filters however I wanted to know if there was something akin to `{% now "Y" %}` - which works for the current year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the format `F` with [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#now):

```
The current month is: {% now "F" %}
```

A list of the format specifiers can be found at [date formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Answer (score 2):

The full tag to print just the current month is `{% now "F" %}`.

You can also do something like this:

```
{% now "F" as current_month %}
{% blocktrans %} 
    The current month is: "{{ current_month }}"
{% endblocktrans %}
```

You can find more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#now)